# Use Offcanvas with Bootstrap 3 Navbar Fixed Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a site with a rather big menu, and don't like the collapsed menu that ships with BS3. I want to use a drawer/off canvas menu, such as the one in BS3's offcanvas JS example (or any other plugin that does the trick - must include support for dropdowns), but the example only does it on a sidebar menu/nav. How can I make it work with my current nav?

Here is the example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

I need that functionality, but applied to the top menu rather than the sidebar.

HTML

```
<nav id="navbar-main" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" id="menu-trigger" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for anybody who has this issue I figured it out using [Jasny Bootstrap](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/)'s Offcanvas feature.

Working example: http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navbar-offcanvas/

Comment: does this require the entire Jasny bootstrap or can you use just the offcanvas plugin?

Comment: You should be able to make it work with just the offcanvas plugin, since the entire JS is just all the scripts compiled together.

Comment: EDIT: Depending on what you want to accomplish you may also need the navmenu files.

Comment: What a coincidence. I had forgotten about this thread and just used Jasny again a couple of weeks ago. You should get it working with the "Reveal" option of the Offcanvas. Check it out: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/

Comment: apparently works really bad if the navmenu overflows. tested in chrome emulator and android default browser.